# If I want to develop php app in linux , which version of linux is best?

Tags: php, linux

If I want to develop php app in linux , which version of linux is best?

Comment: Whichever flavor you can get up and running on your box...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, PHP will perform identically no matter what flavour of Operating System you are using (there are, of course, minor caveats when dealing with Windows, specifically with regards to file locations, etc.)

Whether you are using Ubuntu, or Fedora, or any other version of Linux, you should not find any major effects on your ability to create PHP applications.

As Justin Ethier says - use whatever Linux version is the fastest and easiest for you to install.

Comment: thanks,I choice the Ubuntu,but should I get the Ubuntu Server Edition or Ubuntu Desktop Edition?

Comment: Server Edition, from memory, is a bit more geeky than Desktop (as it is designed to run "headless", that is without a screen attached, and with a text-based interface - the Desktop edition has a graphic user interface which may be easier to navigate. So I would recommend Desktop Version.